# Запустить Flash в браузере

Tags: flash

Есть проект на flash состоящий из множества .swf и .html файлов, .swf работают по отдельности и друг с другом связаны только через веб, как можно запустить flash в браузере, учитывая, что проект находиться локально на компьютере?

Пробовал Ruffle, его ещё не доделали. Пробовал ставить старые версии flash, при попытке воспроизвести любую флешку перебрасывает на сайт adobe. Пробовал разные браузеры и разные плагины.

Comment: Флеш разве не устарел?.. потому и перебрасывает, ибо его выпиливают. Если прям очень надо - смените на компьютере дату на год назад и он должен заработать

Comment: Флеш устарел, но мне бы хотелось иметь представление, как всё выглядело раньше, пока я его переписываю на другой язык. Смена даты на компьютере не помогает, флеш запущенный через браузер перенаправляет на сайт adobe. Проект стартует с index.html.

Comment: Значит ищите какой-нибудь крякнутый флеш или браузер с ним. 100% имеются такие. Мне смена даты помогает, на год назад поставил - обновляю страницу и грузит флеш на вин10

Comment: Помогло chrome flash edition + перемотка времени, спасибо большое!